# Pydantic validation errors with None values

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a returned result from a webservice, whose values come as they are (see example). The keys are not Optional and must be included.

**2 validation errors for Result**:

- *cause* - `str type expected (type=type.error.str)`
- *urls*  - `str type expected (type=type.error.str)`

```json
{ 'code': 0, 'codetext': 'blablabla', 'status': None, 'cause': None, 'urls': None }
```

```python
class Result(BaseModel):
  
  code: int
  codetext: str
  status: str = ""
  cause: str = ""
  urls: str = ""

  @validator("status", "cause", "urls")
  def replace_none(cls, v):
    return v or "None"
```

First questions is, what is the correct way to handle the *None* values coming as answer from the webservice and set to *'None'* (with single-quotation marks and None as String) and secondly, why are there only 2 and not 3 errors?

Comment: Could you rephrase what do you expect to happen to those `None`s? If you want to accept them as input, you should mark them optional.To your second question, at least pydantic 1.9.0 errors on all fields (with a different, clearer error: `none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)`

Comment: @teprrr entered an explanation, what I expect. Thank you for your advice. AFAIK Optional allows to have the property or not, but I got a constraint to definitive have it.

Comment: There's a difference between "The key must be present" and "The key must not have `null` as a value". (I'm assuming that the `None` comes from a JSON `null` value.)

Comment: @chepner Everything you said is true. In the end both conditions must be met at the same time, not None (in a sense of a void, when the Webservice returns nothing) AND the properties will have to be present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [mark fields as required but optional by declaring the field optional and using ellipsis (`...`) as its value](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#required-optional-fields). Here is a complete, simplified example with tests to verify it works (execute with `pytest <file>`):

```
import pytest
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator


class Result(BaseModel):
    code: int
    status: str | None = ...

    @validator("status")
    def replace_none(cls, v):
        return v or "None"


def test_result():
    p = Result.parse_obj({"code": 1, "status": "test status"})
    assert p.code == 1
    assert p.status == "test status"


def test_required_optionals():
    """Test that missing fields raise an error."""
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        Result.parse_obj({"code": 1})


def test_required_optional_accepts_none():
    """Test that none values are accepted."""
    p = Result.parse_obj(
        {
            "code": 0,
            "status": None,
        }
    )
    assert p.status == "None"
```

Comment: The line `status: str | None = ...` wouldn't work, because of `E   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'`. I replaced it with `status: Optional[str] = Field(...)` and it works.

Comment: Ah, [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) allowing that form of optionals is indeed available first since python 3.10. If really wanted, there's a way to use that since 3.7 by adding the following to the top of the file: [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) but I'm not sure if it works with pydantic as I presume it expects concrete types.

Comment: Plus one. In the end you helped to get back on track. import from future was helpful.

Comment: Nobody asked to make fields optional. Optional fields lead to a shitload of type-juggling shenanigans down the line. Is there a way to make it `required`, but replaced by validator if None? Seems like no.

Comment: But how can a field be both required AND optional? Are not these mutually exclusive?